# populating a python dictionary with text file

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, text-files

I am trying to populate a python dictionary by looping through the file. The text file reads like so:

```
Gen 1:1 "some text"
Gen 1:2 "some more text"
```

I am trying to populate the dictionary-making the key being the reference "Gen 1:1" and so on.

Please point me in the right direction. I am willing to do the foot work.

Comment: Is each key value pair on a separate line in the text file, or is it all together?

Comment: Start by creating a dictionary, and then `open` the file.

Comment: the key value pairs on not necessarily on the same line. There could be several lines with one reference such as Gen 1:3 lets say. It might have three lines all within gen 1:3

Comment: Consider using regular expression.

Comment: `line = line.split(" \"")`, `dictionary[line[0]]=line[:-1]` While it may seem complicated, this splits the title and the text using apostrophes and sets the dictionary item minus the last apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much information about the file structure, but it looks like regular expressions might be a good solution.

```
>>> import re
>>> path = '<path.to.the.file>'
>>> with open(path, 'r') as f:
>>>     lines = f.readlines()
>>> rex = re.compile(r'(Gen \d+:\d+) +\"(.*)\"')
>>> data = {}
>>> for line in lines:
>>>     match = rex.match(line)
>>>     if match:
>>>         data[match[1]] = match[2]
>>> data
{'Gen 1:1': 'some text', 'Gen 1:2': 'some more text'}
```

you can test above regular expression at: https://regex101.com/r/6vDT9w/1